# Интерфейс hwmon и модуль ядра lm63

Tags: linux

Посоветуйте пожалуйста, где можно почитать про :

1. Описание интерфейса `hwmon` ядра Linux
2. Модуль ядра `lm63`.

Гуглил, гуглил - ничего не нашёл, кроме как цену модуля `lm63`.=(

Comment: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/hwmon/lm63

Comment: https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/hwmon/lm63

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lm-sensors_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/117654/

Comment: мммм,спасибо , а про интерфейс hwmon есть что-то?

Comment: Изучайте сайт https://www.kernel.org/doc/